# How can I test the connection prior to the scheduled time of a Google hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

Any way within Google Hangouts, to test the connection?

For example, are there any Google Hangouts one can just drop into, with people in different countries so I can test the connection?

Sometimes prior to joining a Google hangout, I want to check if the connection is OK.

I've had a situation, for example, where a connection with somebody in India or Pakistan wasn't good. Or even a connection with somebody in a nearer country.

Say I have a hangout I'm meant to join at a particular time. How can I test the connection prior to that hangout starting?